# I want to position two headers centered in a fixed sized div and both of them should be left-aligned

Tags: html, css

I have to design a circle with two h3 in it. Both of them should line up at the left side but still be centered in the circle.

I already have positioned everything right but I dont know how to left-align both `<h3>`.

Here is the [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B3vdz/).

Ok I guess I explained it wrong. I want the `<h3>` lined-up left. But both maybe wrapped up in another element should be centered in the circle referring to the `<h3>` with the greatest `width`. But the text in there is a sample text. I cannot give a wrapping element a fixed `width` and position it with `margin: 0 auto`.

Comment: how exactly is "line up at the left side but still centered"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the H3 elements in their own div and position it using `margin: 0 auto`.

Once that is done, you can simply left or right align the text within the div.

eg:

```
<div class="h3Wrapper">
  <h3>Foo</h3>
  <h3>Bar</h3>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.h3Wrapper { margin: 0 auto; }
h3 { text-align: left;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `text-align:center` and use `margin:auto`. Please check http://jsfiddle.net/B3vdz/7/. I hope this is how you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this how yout want it?
I used a new div for the text.

`#lefft{
    width: 90px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 50px;
    position: relative;
}`

http://jsfiddle.net/B3vdz/1/